# Blazor masking input with jquery not work

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-client-side

I need input with masked for date and time . I don't want to use date picker. I am using  jquery.inputmask with interop. But input binding not work .

Comment: When asking a question it is always good to show some code. Maybe even create a blazorfiddle (https://blazorfiddle.com/). This will make it more likely for you to get an answer.

Comment: I added blazorfiddle link . But here cant produce masking.  https://blazorfiddle.com/s/5gw8fy1f